# Исправить цикл добавления числа в listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Помогите исправить - Добавления числа 20 в каждую строку колонки "Total"

```
 for (int itt = 1; itt < listView1.Items.Count; itt++)
    {
            int Totall = 20;
            listView1.Items[itt].SubItems["Total"].Add(Totall);

    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Valery Losev вообще смотрели на ошибку ?

Comment: *Зевая*... Я ещё раз говорю: возьмите DataGridView вместо ListView и жизнь станет легче.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov я не буду брать DataGridView, по собственным причинам

Comment: listView1.Items[itt].SubItems["Total"].Text = Totall;

Comment: Расскажите как создается этот `listView` (колонки и элементы). В колонке уже есть какие-то значения и Вы хотите что-то прибавить или Вы хотите везде проставить 20.

Comment: @default locale  там нет ничего пустая ячейка, просто хочу поставить 20

Comment: Ну тогда вроде ответ @ValeryLosev должен подойти.

Comment: По его способу говорит что доступно только для чтения

Comment: @АндрейReyz, свойство Text не указали, как в моем примере.
SubItems["Total"].Text